# PlayReady DRM with Windows Media Foundation

Tags: windows, ms-media-foundation, playready

does somebody know a sample code for plain win32/64 bit applications using windows media foundation and DRM support?
I found a very old sample code here:
https://github.com/GoshaDE/SuperMFLib/blob/master/samples/ProtectedPlayback/Player.cs

But this does not really work.

Regards
Christian

Comment: [It's in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/how-to-play-protected-media-files)

Comment: I probably should mention that I use IMFMediaEngineClassFactory and it does not work, even the old demos from Microsoft in C# do not work. I did not use MFCreatePMPMediaSession since it does not support Dash content.

Comment: It's likely that you might be forced to use newer UWP API to work with PlayReady and underlying implementation of protected MF pipeline. It's not really flexible yet it works, and smaller pieces of DRM pipeline are intentially not documented and are not generally usable otherwise.